# UDPClient constructor keeps throwing error: 10022

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

The code below always throws an exception at the statement: UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(); 
The error code it throws is 10022 which is invalid argument. I'm unsure how the constructor could throw this error.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Test_UDP_Console_program
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int listenPort = 4999;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient();
                receivingUdpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.255"), 4999));
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string returnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                receivingUdpClient.Close();
            }
            catch(SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ErrorCode.ToString());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out when using sockets you have to run the program from a local drive and not a networked drive for some reason.